# Opera: column-count with max-height

Tags: css, overflow, opera

I have a problem in Opera 12 when trying to combine column-count with max-height. The problem is that when there is some fixed height Opera generates more columns than specified in column-count instead of adding scroll.

For example, try following html:

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>1</li> <li>2</li> <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li> <li>5</li> <li>6</li>
        <li>7</li> <li>8</li> <li>9</li>
        <li>11</li> <li>12</li> <li>13</li>
        <li>14</li> <li>15</li> <li>16</li>
        <li>17</li> <li>18</li> <li>19</li>
        <li>21</li> <li>22</li> <li>23</li>
        <li>24</li> <li>25</li> <li>26</li>
        <li>27</li> <li>28</li> <li>29</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

with following css:

```
div
{
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    column-count: 2; -moz-column-count: 2; -webkit-column-count: 2; 
    max-height: 100px;
}
```

You can see the result also at [http://jsfiddle.net/bYhFg/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/bYhFg/5/)

It works fine in Firefox/Chrome, but not in Opera. In Opera it generates more columns than specified i.e. more than two.

What I'm trying to achieve is to make fixed height div with two columns and vertical scroll when needed.

Answer (score 3):

Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/bYhFg/8/):

```
div {
    overflow-x: hidden; 
    overflow-y: auto; 
    max-height: 100px; 
}
ul {
    column-count: 2; -moz-column-count: 2; -webkit-column-count: 2; 
}
```

Comment: Can we do anything without changing styles of the inner list?